# Indian with Sweden work permit. What are the visa requirement for a Republic of Ireland visit?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, ireland, sweden, work-permit

I have a valid work permit and have been working in Sweden for 6 months. I want to visit the Republic of Ireland. What is the visa requirement for this?

Answer (score 10):

Your Swedish work and residence permit is irrelevant.

To visit the Republic of Ireland as an Indian citizen, you need to obtain a visa in advance. You can find information about [how to apply](https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/sweden/our-services/visas/visas-for-ireland/) from the Irish embassy in Sweden.

Comment: I would expect the permit to be very much relevant in the process, but only indirectly. For a Swedish legal resident, the suspicion of illegal immigration would be reduced quite a lot.

Comment: And yes, it *is* somewhat absurd that Ireland doesn't just let Schengen visa holders enter without a visa, but sadly bureaucracy is not built on logic.

Comment: @JonathanReez The Common Travel Area dates back (in various forms) to the establishment of the Irish Free State in 1922, 60+ years before Schengen zone was established. Not letting Schengen visa holders enter ROI without a visa makes sense in the context of the Northern Ireland Protocol and the unique circumstances of an ‘invisible land border’ on the island of Ireland.

Comment: @Traveller The CTA is not significantly different from the Nordic Passport Union and there, they managed to overlap the Schengen Area with the passport union, even by letting non-EU members join the Schengen area. If Ireland and UK had wanted to join Schengen, it would have been possible to find a solution without the CTA being a problem.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo IMHO you are overlooking the complex political situation on the island of Ireland itself and in its relations with the UK. I doubt the Nordic Passport Union was ever hampered by vastly different unionist/nationalist objectives, or a history of terrorist violence, for example.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo They key difference is that the UK does not wish to be in the Schengen area. The non-EU countries in the Nordic passport union could be included in Schengen only because they were OK with that. The CTA basically means that Ireland has to mirror the UK’s border policies as far as movement of people goes.

Comment: @MikeScott Exactly. Because they do not want to join. Not because it is impossible to join because of the CTA.

Comment: @Traveller you can recognize Schengen visas without being a part of the Schengen area. Plenty of countries do so, including Bulgaria and Romania.

Comment: @JonathanReez My point is that politically the CTA is much more than ‘illogical bureaucracy’. Bulgaria and Romania both want to join Schengen. On the basis that the UK has never subscribed to that vision, it would then be pretty illogical for it to accept Schengen visas. Equally, Schengen does not allow entry to UK visa holders.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It’s impossible for _Ireland_ to join Schengen because of the CTA, given the UK’s attitude to Schengen.

Comment: @MikeScott I have not said anything else, but the problem ist that UK does not want to join, not that the CTA exists. In addition to the Nordic Passport Unions, there have been several other 'CTA like' areas in Europe (groups of countries with simplified immigration procedures inbetween) and all have managed to join the Schengen area without conflicts with their previous agreements. So again: Ireland and UK are not prevented from joining the Schengen area because of the CTA, but because either of the countries won't join.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The UK not wanting to join Schengen is not a *’problem’*, it is the UK exercising its sovereign right to decide how it controls its borders. Regardless of whether Ireland joining Schengen whilst remaining within the CTA is theoretically possible, the critical issue you are overlooking is that such a scenario would require establishing a hard border between ROI and NI, the avoidance of which is a key element of the Good Friday Agreement that ended decades of violent conflict.

Comment: @Traveller I am not overlooking anything, but still claiming that while roundabout 30 European countries have joined the Schengen area to cooperate and simplify the lives for their more than 400 million residents, it is a problem, that UK stick with their medieval protectionism and remain outside.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Live and let live, I say. Those roundabout 30 countries are doing what they want to do. One small country is doing what it wants to do by remaining outside that group. There is no ‘problem’‍♀️

Answer (score 5):

As a visa-national you require a visa to travel to the Republic of Ireland regardless of where you reside, unless you have an in date EUFAM card, or a BIVS visa.

Source [Irish Immigration](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/visit-ireland-travel-path/)

Comment: *or a BIVS visa* a regular UK visa may also be accepted under the Irish short stay visa waiver programme, if it has first been used to enter the UK.